# Call method of Existing Instance of AppController from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a class called `AppController`, 
And I have following method in `AppDelegate` which is invoked when menu item is selected.

```
-(IBAction)selectSug:(id) sender
{

    AppController * vc = [[AppController alloc]init];

    [vc selectSugItem:sender];

}
```

But this method creates a new instance of `AppController` so I cannot use existing values of the variables in the `AppController`.

Please help me with a solution.Thanks

Comment: Where do you instantiate the `AppController`? Let the instance as global and use it.

Comment: @trick14 AppController is the class which contains all the code that is working with the mainMenu.xib (UI), it is the only class in the project other than AppDelegate. I don't see instantiation off AppController any where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `AppController` class is meant to be a singleton (meaning there should only be one instance of it that the rest of the application will access), you can simply create one.

Add this method to your `AppController` class (and add the header declaration):

```
+ (instancetype)shared
{
    static id shared = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        shared = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
```

Then you can call it by doing this:

```
-(IBAction)selectSug:(id) sender
{
    AppController * vc = [AppController shared];

    [vc selectSugItem:sender];
}
```